# Silencing Command Output from For in a Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, batch-file, command

The following Code Snippet does exactly what I want it to do if the SRV record is present, which is print out each server withing the SRV record.  However,  if the SRV record isn't found (which is expected in some circumstances, I see the error.

```
:: Execute a Nslookup for the internal SRV Record and collect the FQDNs of the response
:TESTPUBLICDNS
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=" %%f in (`c:\Windows\System32\nslookup.exe -q^=srv %publicSRV%%domain% ^| findstr /R /C:"hostname"`) do (
    set "hostFQDNFull=%%f"
    
    :: Split the result to extract just the FQDN of the servers in the SRV Record
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (`echo !hostFQDNFull!`) do set label=%%a&set hostFQDN=%%b
        set hostFQDN=!hostFQDN: =!
        echo !hostFQDN!
)
```

So if the SRV Record is Present, I'll get:

```
server1.wdgets.com
server2.wdgets.com
server3.wdgets.com
```

But if it's not, I get:

```
*** dnsserver.local can't find _sanitizedsrv._tcp.widgets.com: Non-existent domain
```

I want to silence the "Non-existent" domain output when that is the result.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  If I redirect the For loop to Null I lose the results in the Do section.

Comment: Redirect the error message to NUL `myprogram.exe 2>NUL`

Comment: Change `^|` to `2^>NUL ^|`.